# Translating my query from using aggregate functions to using window functions

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, window-functions, presto

I have a table (`wallet_credit_details`) where each row is a single transaction made by a single customer. There is another table (`wallet_usage_details`) which shows how each user paid for these transactions. What I would like to do is - for each row (transaction) in the first table, aggregate (count and sum) values by the customer from the second table up to the date of the transaction in the first table.

An example of this would be for each transaction, count the number of previous transactions by the same customer which we paid for using "Topups".

```
SELECT
    wallet.customer_id,
    wallet.credit_id AS transaction_id,
    COALESCE(COUNT(usage.debit_id), 0) AS transactions_paid_count_to_date,
    COALESCE(SUM(usage.used_amt_usd), 0) AS transactions_paid_amount_to_date,
    COALESCE(COUNT(CASE WHEN usage.credit_title = 'Topups' AND usage.credit_type = 'Credit Card Topups' THEN 1 END), 0) AS topups_used_count_to_date,
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN usage.credit_title = 'Topups' AND usage.credit_type = 'Credit Card Topups' THEN usage.used_amt_usd END), 0) AS topups_used_amount_to_date
FROM
    prod_dwh.wallet_credit_details AS wallet
LEFT JOIN
    prod_dwh.wallet_usage_details AS usage
ON
    wallet.customer_id = usage.user_id
    AND usage.transaction_date < wallet.day
WHERE
    wallet.credit_title = 'Topups'
    AND wallet.credit_type = 'Credit Card Topups'
    AND wallet.day >= DATE '{min_date}'
    AND wallet.day <= DATE '{max_date}'
GROUP BY
    wallet.customer_id,
    wallet.credit_id
```

How can I reproduce the same logic using a window function?

Comment: you need columns from both tables. You cannot avoid the join.

Comment: I see, my bad. I've edited my question - I'd still like to know how to use window functions in this case to see if performance improves

Comment: f ex. Instead of `COUNT(usage.debit_id) ... GROUP BY  wallet.customer_id,    wallet.credit_id   ` you would say `COUNT(usage.debit_id) OVER (PARTITION BY  wallet.customer_id, wallet.credit_id  )`

Comment: I don't think you need window functions for your example.